# Best practice for displaying a number upto 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function in which I am returning a string, that consists of a decimal number.

If the number is a whole number, then I am returning the number as it is, along with some strings and if it's not, then I am returning the number, along with the string, up to 2 decimal places. My code works fine without any issue. But, I am not sure, if my conversion to decimal places, as well as returning of the string is actually a best practice or not.

```
function getDec() {
  let size_new: string;

  while (size >= 1000) {
    // Do some calculations
    size_new = size_new / 1000;
  }

  //Check whether size is a decimal or not
  return size_in_decimal;
}
```

Comment: Since formatting is a presentation level of concern you should think to create a pipe that displays it as it desired. Your function should return actual number and your pipe should format it.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is fine, but you can simplify it:

```
const getDec = size => {
   while (size >= 1000) size = size / 1000;
   return size.toFixed(2 * !!(size % 1)) + ' GB';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Intl.NumberFormat to format numbers, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'decimal' }).format(size)
```